# How to get any result while scraping this website with selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I am scraping the website with this code but it does not give me any result.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

#suit = []
url = 'https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616'
#   time.sleep(2)

# print(url)
driver.get(url)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: How is it about webdriver?

Comment: `requests` is using a native `HTTP` request! `1.` there's no need to use `headers=False`, instead using `headers=headers` which uou already specified earlier. `2.` Secondly, pass `r.content` as there's no `page_source` method within `requests`. `3.` the website which you dealing with is using `JavaScript` to render it's content so you are highly advised to use `selenium` or check for an `API`

Comment: I add web driver but i not responding also i try to find api but here they disable api for users

Comment: @MuhammadUmer then [edit] your code and show us your selenium code and specify your issue!

Comment: import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

#suit = []
url = 'https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616'
#   time.sleep(2)

# print(url)
driver.get(url)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource,'lxml')
print(soup)
not working

Comment: @MuhammadUmer comment section is not for asking a question, Please click on [edit] and modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to get the info from that page (of course, you can get more info, per categories, etc):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
articles = soup.select('article[data-auto-id="productTile"]')
for art in articles:
    print(art.text)
```

Result:

```
ASOS DESIGN t-shirt with crew neck in white - WHITE£6.00
ASOS DESIGN t-shirt with crew neck in black - BLACK£6.00
COLLUSION white t-shirt£5.99
COLLUSION black t-shirt£5.99
adidas Originals 'Sports Resort' Club t-shirt in white with back graphics£30.00
ASOS DESIGN cotton blend muscle fit t-shirt with crew neck in black - BLACK£6.00
ASOS DESIGN t-shirt with crew neck in white£6.00
COLLUSION Unisex oversized t-shirt with sun print in charcoal£15.99
The North Face Simple Dome logo t-shirt in green Exclusive at ASOS£24.00
adidas Training Train 365 logo vest in black£22.00
ASOS DESIGN t-shirt in beige with front city print£12.00
Pull&Bear Join Life t-shirt in white£9.99
French Connection crew neck t-shirt in black£10.00
Nike Running Run Dri-FIT t-shirt in peach£17.95
adidas Originals Happy Earth large back print earth trefoil logo t-shirt in off white£30.00
ASOS DESIGN 3 pack oversized t-shirt in multi£28.00
Topman oversized t-shirt in black£12.00
Vans left chest logo t-shirt in teal£21.00
COLLUSION oversized t-shirt with banana print in white£14.99
[...]
```

You don't need Selenium for this job. Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Also, BeautifulSoup docs can be found at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @platipus_on_fire it is not necessary to use [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/#putting-everything-together) but if so may start from a [more up to date version](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#python) and check [`docs`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/#putting-everything-together)

**Note:** *[executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#python-1)*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616'

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
data = []

for e in soup.select('article'):
    data.append({
        'title': e.h2.text,
        'price': e.p.text,
        'url': e.a.get('href')
    })
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'ASOS DESIGN t-shirt with crew neck in white - WHITE',
  'price': '£6.00',
  'url': 'https://www.asos.com/asos-design/asos-design-t-shirt-with-crew-neck-in-white-white/prd/22190861?clr=white&colourWayId=60380327&cid=7616'},
 {'title': 'ASOS DESIGN t-shirt with crew neck in black - BLACK',
  'price': '£6.00',
  'url': 'https://www.asos.com/asos-design/asos-design-t-shirt-with-crew-neck-in-black-black/prd/22190857?clr=black&colourWayId=60380297&cid=7616'},
 {'title': 'COLLUSION white t-shirt',
  'price': '£5.99',
  'url': 'https://www.asos.com/collusion/collusion-white-t-shirt/prd/202692601?clr=white&colourWayId=202692607&cid=7616'},
 {'title': 'COLLUSION black t-shirt',
  'price': '£5.99',
  'url': 'https://www.asos.com/collusion/collusion-black-t-shirt/prd/202692520?clr=black&colourWayId=202692530&cid=7616'},
 {'title': "adidas Originals 'Sports Resort' Club t-shirt in white with back graphics",
  'price': '£30.00',
  'url': 'https://www.asos.com/adidas-originals/adidas-originals-sports-resort-club-t-shirt-in-white-with-back-graphics/prd/201829282?clr=white&colourWayId=201829292&cid=7616'},...]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @platipus_on_fire here it will be done by using BeautifulSoup see @Muhammad Umer here is the code which will help you out

**

### Example

**

```
  import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time
    time.sleep(4)
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
    }


r = requests.get('https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
articles = soup.find_all('a',class_='B36cezB')
for art in articles:
    title= art.find('div',class_ = 'fgoiFbk')
    title1=title.find('div',class_='zrNElLX').text
    pprice= art.find('span',class_ ='CMH3V3f').text
    try:
        discount_price=art.find('span',class_='C4AGBY0').text
    except:
        discount_price='NONE'
    print('Product_Name:',title1,'\nProduct_Price:',pprice,'\nProduct_discount_price:',discount_price)
```

**Code Output**

```
Product_Name: adidas Originals Happy Earth large back print earth trefoil logo t-shirt in off white
Product_Price: £30.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: AllSaints Underground oversized t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £49.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Tommy Hilfiger classic logo t-shirt in dark grey
Product_Price: £40.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Simple Dome logo t-shirt in green Exclusive at ASOS
Product_Price: £24.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Fred Perry embroidered t-shirt in white
Product_Price: £45.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN 3 pack oversized t-shirt in multi
Product_Price: £28.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN 5 pack t-shirt with crew neck in multi
Product_Price: £28.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Levi's 2 pack t-shirt in white/black with babytab logo
Product_Price: £30.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Mountain Line t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £27.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Topographic back print t-shirt in white Exclusive at ASOS
Product_Price: £27.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Polo Ralph Lauren icon logo t-shirt in beige marl
Product_Price: £65.00 
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Nike oversized heavyweight t-shirt with embroidered logo in mint foam
Product_Price: £32.95
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Reebok camping graphic tee in burgundy  - Exclusive to ASOS
Product_Price: £23.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: COLLUSION Unisex oversized t-shirt with sun print in charcoal
Product_Price: £15.99
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN 5 pack t-shirt with crew neck
Product_Price: £28.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Vans Small Logo t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £20.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Nike sole craft back print t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £37.95
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Under Armour Training Tech 2.0 t-shirt in grey marl
Product_Price: £23.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Under Armour t-shirt with tonal logo in black
Product_Price: £22.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Under Armour Training tech 2.0 1/2 zip top in black
Product_Price: £34.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Vans left chest logo t-shirt in teal
Product_Price: £21.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Topman classic fit t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £8.00
Product_discount_price: £7.00
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN 2 pack t-shirt with crew neck save - MULTI
Product_Price: £10.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Topman oversized t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £12.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN t-shirt in beige with front city print
Product_Price: £12.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: French Connection crew neck t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £10.00 
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Nike Club t-shirt in khaki beige
Product_Price: £17.95
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Mountain Outline t-shirt in white Exclusive at ASOS
Product_Price: £32.00
Product_discount_price: £24.00
Product_Name: Under Armour Training Tech 2.0 t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £23.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: French Connection crew neck t-shirt in white
Product_Price: £10.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN cotton t-shirt with crew neck in charcoal marl - GREY
Product_Price: £6.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Red Box back print t-shirt in turtle brown Exclusive at ASOS
Product_Price: £27.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: COLLUSION Unisex oversized logo t-shirt in purple
Product_Price: £8.99
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: COLLUSION Unisex logo t-shirt in pink
Product_Price: £7.99
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Simple Dome logo t-shirt in blue Exclusive at ASOS
Product_Price: £24.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: adidas Originals Rekive central logo t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £33.00
Product_discount_price: £26.50
Product_Name: COLLUSION Unisex oversized t-shirt with logo graphic in white
Product_Price: £15.99
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Red Box t-shirt in white
Product_Price: £27.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN Cotton Blend t-shirt with scoop neck - WHITE
Product_Price: £6.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Simple Dome logo t-shirt in pale pink Exclusive at ASOS
Product_Price: £24.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: COLLUSION Unisex logo t-shirt in brown
Product_Price: £8.99
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN cotton blend t-shirt with scoop neck - BLACK
Product_Price: £6.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: COLLUSION oversized logo t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £8.99 
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Timberland Dunstan River t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £25.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: River Island regular fit t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £8.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Only & Sons oversized t-shirt with Japanese river back print in white
Product_Price: £15.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Nike Retro pack t-shirt in grey heather
Product_Price: £37.95
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: New Balance small logo t-shirt in black
Product_Price: £18.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN oversized t-shirt in black with street spine print
Product_Price: £18.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Levi's t-shirt with box tab logo in blue
Product_Price: £20.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: ASOS DESIGN oversized t-shirt with crew neck in white - WHITE
Product_Price: £12.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: The North Face Red Box back print t-shirt in blue Exclusive at ASOS
Product_Price: £27.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
Product_Name: Jack & Jones Originals oversized t-shirt with plant back print in white
Product_Price: £15.00
Product_discount_price: NONE
```